# Tab mis-interpreted by RichTextBox

Tags: c#, rtf, stringwriter

I have RTF that is being mis-interpreted.  `StringWriter` takes a `\t` and replaces it with some character that `RichTextBox` cannot deal with inside a table.

```
string rtfBeforeConversion = @"{\rtf1{\trowd\cellx1150 \cellx3750 \cellx7350 Temp\intbl\cell 96 - 99.7\t\intbl\cell 97.9\t\intbl\cell \row}}";
string rtfBrokenByConversion = @"{\rtf1{\trowd\cellx1150 \cellx3750 \cellx7350 Temp\intbl\cell 96 - 99.7    \intbl\cell 97.9    \intbl\cell \row}}";
```

`rtfBeforeConversion` correctly displays 3 columns with data in a `RichTextBox`.

`rtfBrokenByConversion` results in the 3rd column displaying no data (or data outside and to the right of it's column depending on the DLL being used to interpret the RTF).

**Stringwriter code**

```
 using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                GetRTF(sw);//inserts value of rtfBeforeConversion
                return sw.ToString();//ToString() creates rtfBrokenByConversion
            }
```

How can I correct this problem?  (Note that I tried `StringBuilder` and had the same results)

Comment: " It's inserted by `StringWriter`" Could you share the code that writes to `StringWriter` the thing(s) that become the string in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like other special characters `\r, \n,`, `\t` cannot be readily used inside of RTF.  The character needs to be converted to it's RTF equivalent.  In this case I created an extension to clean the ill formatted text:

```
    public static string ConvertTabs(this string poorlyFormedRtf)
    {
        string unicodeTab = "\u0009";
        string result = poorlyFormedRtf.Replace(unicodeTab, "\\tab");
        return result;
    }
```

Now everything looks great.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the character in that specific string by looking at the character that is after 99.7 like this:

```
string s = @"{\rtf1{\trowd\cellx1150 \cellx3750 \cellx7350 Temp\intbl\cell 96 - 99.7    \intbl\cell 97.9    \intbl\cell \row}}";
char c = s[s.IndexOf("99.7", 0) + 4]; //char you want
int x = (int) c;
string unicodeHexCode = x.ToString("X"); //hex code for char you want
```

x will give you the integer value of the unicode character
while unicodeHexCode will give you the hex value.